# I can't compile source, make doesn't work

Tags: installation, command-line, drivers, make

I am trying to install "Somagic EasyCAP DC60" device driver step by step from a guide.
I'm in the unpacked folder in Terminal, but `make` doesn't work. It says:

```
me@me-PC:~/Desktop/somagic-easycap_1.1$ make
cc -s -W -Wall somagic-init.c -o somagic-init -lusb-1.0 -lgcrypt
make: cc: Command not found
make: *** [somagic-init] Error 127
```

I tried `sudo make` but it's the same. All dependencies and packages are installed that the guide says.

Here is the guide:
http://code.google.com/p/easycap-somagic-linux/wiki/GettingStarted#somagic-capture_Debian_package

Comment: Use `build-essential`.Why do you want to compile & build locally? It installs all the unnecessary dependencies on your machine.Instead use `debuild -S` upload to ppa & let the launchpad compile for you.

Answer (score 3):

open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

then try again.

I am sure that's going to help you.

Comment: Thank you! That worked!
But now I stuck at installing the windows driver with wine, setup starts, but I get error message that says there's another installation in progress, or something else. I tried the original driver from the CD, and 3 downloaded version's of the driver. All of them show that same error message. Maybe there's a problem with wine?

Comment: @user224057 that's different question. please start a new question.